# Mix between the enum and list

Tags: c#

My goal is a little mix between the lists  and enum.

Example when I create a list:

```
List<string> toto= new List<string>;
toto.add("test1");
toto.add("test2");
```

==>but it's not possible to call "test1" like this: toto.test1

With the enum it's possible like this:

```
public enum toto{
test,test2
}
```

but it's not possible of create dynamic an enum in terms of string

an idea for my problem?

Thank for your help

Comment: You forgot `c#-5.0` tag...

Comment: "My goal is a little mix between the lists and enum." What is your goal then? You just stated the obvious that you can't call List items with `listname.itemValue`, that's all...

Comment: If it's dynamic in nature, of course the compiler can't help you with static typing. What is the problem behind this that you are trying to solve?

Comment: I think he just wants to access list elements by name...

Comment: @judgeja yes , the idea is access a listElement by the name and not with list.get(1) but list.nameElement

Comment: -1 pointing out things that .NET libraries do not do by default is not a question

Comment: @KirkBroadhust how I know if it's possible or not  in default library if I don't ask the question? If a begginer ask a question and it's not possible with the default library you put -1 ?

Comment: This just isn't how C# works. You are asking for dynamically created properties, which you MIGHT be able to get by using the `dynamic` keyword and some Reflection, but I would encourage you to abandon this. When in Rome, do as the Romans do. Switch languages if you really NEED this functionality to be baked in.

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure what you are trying to do. If you want dynamically expanding objects then :

Why don't you try `ExpandoObject` in .NET 4.0?

```
dynamic toto = new ExpandoObject();
toto.test1 = 10;
toto.test2 = 300;
toto.test3 = "Hello";
```

Comment: but with this method you must create the variable test1&test2&test3 in Object "ExpandObject".  I would like with a word "string" create a list or others and access to the element by the name

Comment: @zoners your question makes no sense. Is there any other language you speak - and if possible get your point across to us?

Answer (score 0):

<s>You could make an extension function, to translate strings from your list to an enum member.</s>

```
    public static MyEnum ToMyEnum(this String myEnumMemberAsString, Boolean ignoreCase = true)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(myEnumMemberAsString))
            throw new ArgumentException("ToMyEnum: String null or empty!");
        return (MyEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), myEnumMemberAsString, ignoreCase);
    }
```

Assuming your list in your question:

```
public static String GetFromList(this List<String> list, MyEnum elemToGet)
{
    return list.SingleOrDefault(e => e == elemToGet.ToString());
}
```

then do for example `String found = list.GetFromList(MyEnum.test2);`

Comment: It's possible you create a little example with List<string> ? I don't understand how works your method

Comment: @Zoners think I misunderstood. See edit.

Comment: It's not resolve my probleme sorry, because your function return a string who exist into enum.  But I Would like access a listElement by your name ...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use such an object only within one method (without passing it anywhere else) you can use anonymous type (starting with 3.0):

```
var container = new 
                  {
                       test1,
                       test2,
                  };

var test1Again = container.test1;
```

Otherwise the only thing you can do is dynamic object because compiler won't be able to verify such usages.